# Codeigniter loading library

Tags: view, controller, codeigniter-2

i have a controller like this one :

```
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script acces allowed');

class Halaman extends CI_controller{
function __controller(){
    parent::controller;
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
    $this->load->library('table');
}

function index(){
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
    $this->load->view('view_halaman');
}
function daftar(){
            $this->load->model(url);
    }
}
```

and i have a views like this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Pembagian menggunakan validasi!!</title> 
</head> 


<body> 
<h1>Daftar Ulang</h1> 
<?php echo form_open('halaman/daftar'); ?>
<?php $data=array(
    array('Field','isi data'),
    array('nama',form_input('user','tulis username')),
    array('password',form_password('pass','password')),
    array('email',form_input('email','tulis email di sini'))
);
echo $this->table->generate($data);
?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<p><br/>Page rendered in {elapsed_time} seconds</p>
</html>
```

enter code here

what i get is this one :
[image: error message]
where is my mistake ? im sorry i am really newbie in codeigniter. thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$table is not a member of the view object.  So you can't call it from the view template.  You need to move the `echo $this->table->generate($data);` to the controller, and either assign it to a view variable or just echo it from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the library wasn't loaded (that's the error in the red lined box). This happends when you don't follow the CI library name conventions. The Table library should be in application/libraries/Table.php and class must be someting like:

```
class Table {
   // Your code
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Also when you load the library, use the name with capital T:

```
$this->load->library('Table');
```

Regards,